# Moving windows phone 8.0 phonegap app from worklight 6.0 to worklight 6.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I migrated windows phone hybrid app from worklight 6.0 to worklight 6.1. We are also using around 13 user plugins apart from cordova Native APIs.

> Starting to migrate the ProjectName project from version 6.0.0 to
>   version 6.1.0.01.20140821-0406.
>   Migrating to Cordova 3.1.0 for Windows
>   Phone 8

App migrates successfully.

After migration, application is not launching after splash-screen.
MainPage.xaml.cs has following code at the starting:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.CordovaView.Browser.LoadCompleted += Browser_LoadCompleted;
```

In working 6.0 app, after InitializeComponent(), VS output lists all the plugins.But in 6.1 app, it doesn't display any plugin.

In working 6.0 app, after this.CordovaView.Browser.LoadCompleted, VS output is

```
CordovaBrowser_Navigated :: /www/default/MainPage.html
CordovaBrowser_Navigated :: ///www/default/MainPage.html
```

But in 6.1, it is not showing CordovaBrowser_Navigated.

Note: worklight 6.0 uses cordova 2.6 and worklight 6.1 uses cordova 3.1.0

Do we have to use node CLI the command line interface to add plugins?

Comment: Windows Phone environment in worklight 6.0 does not give any error when i compile it in Visual Studio

Comment: Try w/out all of your plug-ins. I suspect one of them is interfering.

Comment: Even after removing all the plug-ins, its getting stuck at this line this.CordovaView.Browser.LoadCompleted                                                                 Cordova browser is not getting rended.

Comment: Have you tried with the very latest 6.1 iFix? you are using an older version, from 6.1.0.1 where as by now there is 6.1.0.2

Comment: Idan, can you provide the link to download the fix pack?

Comment: As an IBM customer you can get it from IBM fix central website.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do the same operation with  simple project for Windows Phone 8 Hybrid app from WL6.0 and migrated it to WL 6.1, the build seems to fail because of lock in the files in the native project. it seems to be an issue in the tool.

Error message:
[2015-01-21 18:27:01] FWLST1040E: windowsphone8 build failed: Destination file 'ZZZZZZ/TestWP8/apps/TestWP8App/windowsphone8/native/.wldata' can not be replaced

Please, contact your IBM support team to open  PMR requesting investigation of the problem.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a simple app in IBM Worlight 6.0;
2. add the windows Phone 8 environment;
3. open the native project on the Visual Studio(to run it on the device)
4. close Visual Studio(not sure if it is optional, but as the nature of the problem is a lock, not sure who is locking it)
5. open WL 6.1 and import the project created on WL 6.0.

At this point the message appears: 
FWLST1040E: windowsphone8 build failed: Destination file '..../TestWP8/apps/TestWP8App/windowsphone8/native/.wldata' can not be replaced'